# Automatically, getting result from azure function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

My azure function produces output result in JSON format (e.g output.json), under **D:\home\site\wwwroot\Simulation\output.json**.
I am struggling to get those (output.json) result automatically in OneDrive or Dropbox (I am not looking to use GitHub). 
Is it possible to automatically access the result file under **D:\home\site\wwwroot\Simulation**\output.json location and move/relocate in different place (e.g: my home desktop, OneDrive, Dropbox or ftp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is use an external file binding. Essentially, instead of saving the file locally, you'll create an output binding. The binding will let you enter your credentials and provide a mechanism to stream the file contents from your function app.

The binding looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "<Name of output parameter in function signature>",
    "type": "apiHubFile",
    "direction": "out",
    "path": "<Path of input file - see below>",
    "connection": "<name of external file connection>"
}
```

You didn't specify language, but assuming C# the code will look something like this:

```
public static void Run(string myQueueItem, out Stream myOutputStream, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
    // logic to write Json to the stream
}
```

Read the full documentation here: https://jlik.me/4l

Comment: Please let me know if you have any example in this case. I am very new in Azure. The **output.json** or **output.txt** is  result file created by **simulation.exe** running thought azure function. That is why I am struggling to put **output.json** file into external storage. Is it possible to put internal file to external location, e.g binding something like: ' {
      "type": "apiHubFile",
      "name": "myOutputStream",
      "direction": "out",
      "path": "D:/home/site/wwwroot/GetFileName/output.txt",
      "connection": "onedrive_ONEDRIVE"
    }'

Comment: Perhaps if you shared the function code we could be of more assistance.

Comment: Hi @Jeremy, here is my code which it produces exe file in D:\home\site\wwwroot\Simulation\output.json location:'info.WorkingDirectory = ProcessWorkingDirectoryInfo;
        info.FileName = ExeLocation;
        info.Arguments = "";
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo = info;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();' I am having problem to store those output.json data into onedrive, dropbox or into database.

Answer (score 1):

To put your output file into external storage like OneDrive or DropBox, use [External File bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-external-file).

You should avoid storing results locally, since functions might be running on different instances over time (if on Consumption plan).

Comment: The **output.json** or **output.txt** is  result file created by **simulation.exe** running thought azure function. That is why I am struggling to put **output.json** file into external storage.

Comment: Please let me know if you have any example in this case. I am very new in Azure. The **output.json** or **output.txt** is  result file created by **simulation.exe** running thought azure function. That is why I am struggling to put **output.json** file into external storage. Is it possible to put internal file to external location, e.g binding something like: ' {
      "type": "apiHubFile",
      "name": "myOutputStream",
      "direction": "out",
      "path": "D:/home/site/wwwroot/GetFileName/output.txt",
      "connection": "onedrive_ONEDRIVE"
    }'